# Intercept request to /wp-content/uploads/random.file

Tags: uploads, actions, init

I want to intercept requests to public files in WordPress, more specifically all requests to any file located in `/wp-content/uploads`. Using `request` or even `init` filters didn't help, e.g.

```php
add_action('init', function() {
    $currentURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($currentURI, '-sab-v') !== false) {
        return;
    }
});
```

should catch the request to `http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/afghanistan-sab-v1-1-586f2f0eb1464db28d20848756de2671.zip`, but doesn't. The same if I use the `request` filter instead. I know the code doesn't do anything, but breakpoints tell me it's not even triggered.

It does of course work for any other WordPress URL, I can successfully intercept all requests except for file downloads.

Anyone got any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran a test where I uploaded an image to media library, then renamed my root index.php file to break Wordpress, but the image I uploaded was still available by accessing it directly with its `wp-content/uploads/...` URL.

There are no .htaccess files in wp-content or uploads either, which means that, barring any plugins that might do some magic to intercept those URLs, access to those files is direct, not through any PHP.

So, to do what you want you'd need to add an .htaccess rule which would intercept these URL's and pass them to a PHP script such as Wordpress's index.php. For example something like this in your root .htaccess would do it:

```
RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ index.php?uploadUrl=$1 [L,NC]
```

Note: This would have be added *above* the Wordpress block so WP did not overwrite and remove it.

You'd then have to catch those URL's before Wordpress processes them to do whatever it is you're trying to do, and a good place for that is the [`template_redirect` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect), which gets run before Wordpress has started figuring out how to render the page.

So something like:

```
function hook_upload_url() {
   if (!empty($_GET['uploadUrl'])) {
       // do your thing, path of this file is in $_GET['uploadUrl']
       // perhaps you want to serve a file, or wp_redirect(), then die()
   }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'hook_upload_url' );
```

Code here is examples of how to achieve what you want, but untested. Please reply with any questions/problems if you do it this way.

Note

- Doing this is probably a very bad idea as it will cause a whole WP instance to be spun up for every single access to any media, which as above does not happen by default. You're at risk of putting a ton more load on your server.
- There might be another or better way to get the URL query param WP style, rather than use $_GET directly

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Also for the new testing strategy, smart:) I'll test that now. It's a headless setup (react app as frontend) where I want to increment the downloads count on free downloadable WC products (which don't go through the usual order process). Intercepting the direct downloads I could manually increment the download counter. So much for reference:)

Comment: It worked!! Well, sorta. I had to get rid of the action since WP isn't loaded at that point. So if I want WP functions available I need to `require_once("/var/www/html/wp-load.php");`. Since I want to return the actual file eventually, I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175533/how-to-return-a-file-in-php. Also, since the files being affected have structured filenames, I altered the apache rule regex a little to `RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/(.*-sab-v.*\.zip)$ wp-content/index.php?uploadUrl=$1 [L,NC]`. Thanks so much! .htaccess logic was the missing piece for me!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. My example was redirecting to the Wordpress index.php, in which cases hooks and all of Wordpress would be available so you could add that hook to e.g. functions.php, but I'm guessing you redirected to your own script so you wouldn't necessarily need to load WP in that case

Comment: BTW, for future reference: if one wants to preserve any previous query strings, you only need to pass a `QSA` flag to the above rule, i.e. `RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/(.*-sab-v.*\.zip)$ wp-content/index.php?uploadUrl=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`