# How to grab query string from wp-content/uploads/.*

Tags: plugin-development, rewrite-rules, query-string

I've written a quick little plugin to grab some custom query_vars, do some manipulation, and store the output in a CSV file. It works great for pages and posts, but ... it seems that queries to wp-content/uploads don't actually go through WordPress, and I want to grab those, too.

I'm thinking of two different approaches:

1. per the answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372114/intercept-request-to-wp-content-uploads-random-file/372120#372120), maybe write a custom rewrite rule, and pass the request into WordPress *iff* it's a query for wp-content/uploads *and* there exists a query string; or,
2. write a standalone PHP program that processes the request from a custom rewrite rule, without worrying about spinning up WordPress.

The problem with (1) is that ... the Internet is a wild and whacky place. While I imagine there will be far fewer requests for wp-content/upload content without query strings than with, it still could end up being a ton of extra load on the server, depending on what happens out there in the wild.

The problem with (2) is, I have to either figure out how to figure out `wp_upload_dir` and `plugin_dir_path` without spinning up wordpress, or I have to stick everything outside of the wordpress hierarchy.

At the moment, I can do the latter, as this is just a quick little hack for one of my sites, but ... it feels so wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: sorry, I do not full understand the question, you want to know how to get all the file names in .../wp-content/uploads/?  you want to know how to get the real path to .../wp-content/uploads/? or is something else?!

Comment: If someone hits ../wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img.png?attr1=foo&attr2=bar I want to get attr1 and attr2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you noted is with the .htaccess rewrite rules which - in the typical wp htaccess file - exclude physical files and directories from being processed by index.php and got served directly.
I think the solution is in working with .htaccess adding a prioritary rule to let a file with query string being processed by php instead of being served directly and loose the query string. I don't think such a rule (well restricted to specific cases) may overload the server, you can easily monitor it and decide wether or not to use it:
try this in your .htaccess:

```
#first condition if the URL contains the path to uploads directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /wp-content/uploads/ [NC] 

#second condition if specific keys are present in the query string (attr1 OR attr2)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attr1= [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attr2=

#third condition we need to avoid infinite loop and errror 500, 
#so we check that a specific key (added in our final rewrite rule below) is not present 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !loop=no

#the final rule if all above is matched will redirect to index.php and add our 'loop=no' key/value pair to avoid the loop
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?loop=no [L,QSA]
```

At this point if you type your url `/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img.png?attr1=foo&attr2=bar` you will get 404 not found.
In your plugin function then:

```
add_action('init','check_attributes');
function check_attributes(){
  if(!empty($_GET['loop']) && $_GET['loop'] =='no'){ //you may add more clause here if needed

    $var1=$_GET['attr1'];
    $var2=$_GET['attr2'];
    // perform your logic with the variables passed to the url
   
    // maybe redirect to the physical file without query vars?
    wp_redirect(strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?'));
    exit;
  }
}
```

Hope it may help